# OpenAI API error: "Your authentication token is not from a valid issuer."

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I was following the Andrew Ng [course on prompt engineering](https://learn.deeplearning.ai/chatgpt-prompt-eng/lesson/2/guidelines) and there they provided us a codeplayground to play with the code and through there I got this

```bash
openai_apikey= "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcHAiLCJzdWIiOiIxNjc0NTM2IiwiYXVkIjoiV0VCIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA2NDY1NzkyLCJleHAiOjE3MDkwNTc3OTJ9.y4NMPAFHZJ2Bnf5oeJAV6RfHwqi4_TAW4nLfCGlv7Lg"
```

using the following code:

```python
import os
import openai
key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
def check_openai_api_key(api_key):
    openai.api_key = api_key
    try:
        openai.Model.list()
    except :
        return False
    else:
        return True


is_valid = check_openai_api_key(key)

if is_valid:
    print("Valid OpenAI API key.")
else:
    print("Invalid OpenAI API key.")
```

In that playground the API key was valid:

[image: Image saying valid openai_apikey in playground]

But when I tried it in my localhost it was invalid:

[image: Image saying invalid key]

Can someone explain the inconsistent behaviour of the API key?

Comment: @brc-dd Thanks for the immediate response, and yes you are absolutely correct it is indeed a correct API key, it is just that I am not a authenticated user . I tried on a new piece of code and the error is "openai.error.AuthenticationError: Your authentication token is not from a valid issuer." Do you have any solution to bypass this error?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The `Your authentication token is not from a valid issuer` error is caused by, as the error says, your API key.

OpenAI API keys always start with `sk`, like this:

```
sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Whereas your "API key" is the following:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcHAiLCJzdWIiOiIxNjc0NTM2IiwiYXVkIjoiV0VCIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA2NDY1NzkyLCJleHAiOjE3MDkwNTc3OTJ9.y4NMPAFHZJ2Bnf5oeJAV6RfHwqi4_TAW4nLfCGlv7Lg
```

By looking at your "API key", I can tell you this is a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/) (i.e., JWT). JWT has:

- Header: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9`
- Payload: `eyJpc3MiOiJhcHAiLCJzdWIiOiIxNjc0NTM2IiwiYXVkIjoiV0VCIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA2NDY1NzkyLCJleHAiOjE3MDkwNTc3OTJ9`
- Signature: `y4NMPAFHZJ2Bnf5oeJAV6RfHwqi4_TAW4nLfCGlv7Lg`

### Solution

Navigate to the [API key page](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) and click *Create new secret key*. This is your OpenAI API key.

Comment: Is there any way to decode the encoded token of jwt?

Comment: @kishanpayadi Yes, you need the secret key that was used for encoding the JWT. Why would you do that? You need an OpenAI API key.

Comment: yeah I was just playing around trying to extract the API key, Cause I dont have one. But i use Gemini pro.